# subquery in andFilterWhere in yii2

Tags: php, yii2, query-builder

I have to execute this query

```
select count(id) as numberofcompanies, sum(offered_value) as total_offered_value from campaign_comapany
       where ( campaign_id in (select id from campaing where user_id = current_user ) or campaing_company.sp_user_id = current_user)
             and campaign_company.status = '3'
```

And I wrote the query like this in yii2-

```
$query->select(['count(id) as numberofcompanies','sum(offered_value) as total_offered_value'])
                                 ->from('campaign_company')
                                 ->andFilterWhere(['or',['in','campaign_id',(new yii\db\Query())->select(['id'])->from('campaign')->where(['=','user_id',Yii::$app->user->id])],['=','campaign_company.sp_user_id',Yii::$app->user->id]])
                                 ->andWhere(['=','status','3'])
                                 ->one();
```

But it gives me error with `unknow column campaign_company.user_id`
but working if I just use `where` like following-

```
$query->select(['count(id) as numberofcompanies','sum(offered_value) as total_offered_value'])
                                 ->from('campaign_company')
                                 ->where(['in','campaign_id',(new yii\db\Query())->select(['id'])->from('campaign')->where(['=','user_id',Yii::$app->user->id])])
                                 ->andWhere(['=','status','3'])
                                 ->one();
```

What should I do to get the result mentioned sql query, I don't want to hit database server two time, thanks in advance

Comment: What about to use DAO,something like this $post = Yii::$app->db->createCommand('SELECT * FROM post WHERE id=1')
           ->queryOne(); (see guide of yii)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use join:

```
$query->select(['count(id) as numberofcompanies','sum(offered_value) as total_offered_value'])
       ->from('campaign_company')
       ->innerJoin('campaign','`campaign`.`id` = `campaign_company`.`campaign_id`') 
       ->where([
           ['=','campaign.user_id',Yii::$app->user->id])],
           ['=','campaign.campaign_company.sp_user_id',Yii::$app->user->id],
           ['=','campaign_company.status','3']
         ]
       ->one();
```

Answer (score 1):

As is it is difficult to follow your logic. To simplify your code and your query, add the first condition as plain sql. Also since the second condition is required, you can swap the positions as follows:

```
$query
    ->select(['count(id) as numberofcompanies','sum(offered_value) as total_offered_value'])
    ->from('campaign_company')
    ->where(['status' => '3'])
    ->andWhere(['
        campaign_id in (select id from campaign where user_id = :current_user )
        or campaign_company.sp_user_id = :current_user1', 
        [':current_user' => Yii::$app->user->id, ':current_user1' => Yii::$app->user->id]])
    ->one();
```